# .net: XmlDocument creates one line xml document

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a standard XML document, which looks like a 'tree'. I add some nodes and save changes:

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();    
    doc.Load(filename);
 ...
    doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
    XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(filename, Encoding.Default); 
    doc.WriteTo(writer);
    writer.Close();
```

and after that xml document stretch into one line. How to add line feeds?

Comment: You should never use `new XmlTextWriter`. That has been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlWriter.Create` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you construct the `XmlTextWriter`, but before you call `doc.WriteTo(writer);`, insert this line:

```
writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
```